# How can I get a hex value in c++ to a proper string?

Tags: c++, database, hex

I am still working on a database for movies and I would like to show the user what he has input to the file.

However when i use `cout << lisafilm <<` it provides me with hex value. Therefore, I need to conver hex to string.

Snippet of trouble.

```
void sisend() 
{ 
     string nimi; 
     int aasta; 
     long int hinne; 
     string vaadatud; 
     ofstream lisafilm("andmebaas.txt", ios::app); 
     cout <<"Sisestage filmi nimi." << endl; 
     cin >> nimi;

     cout << "Sisestage filmi aasta." << endl; 
     cin >> aasta;     

     cout << "Sisestage filmi hinne." << endl; 
     cin >> hinne; 

     cout << "Kas olete filmi juba vaadanud?" << endl;  
     cout << "Vastake 'Jah' voi 'Ei'" << endl; 
     cin >> vaadatud; 

lisafilm<< nimi << "  " << aasta << "  " << hinne<< "  " << vaadatud << endl; 
lisafilm.close();    

{  
 system("CLS"); 
 int hex_str = lisafilm ;

 cout << "Aitah kasutamast andmebaasi." << endl; 
 system("pause"); 
 cin.get (); 
} 
 main(); 

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want a hex value converted into a hex string?
The question is ambiguous.

Comment: When you do `int hex_str = lisafilm` you are trying to convert a stream object to an integer. How is that supposed to be done? Do you want to read from the stream? Or something else? Also, why are you calling the `main` function? This question makes no sense.

Comment: Totally off topic, but I'm curious: what's your native language? I can't tell from the text in the messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << lisafilm;
const std::string s = ss.str();
```

Comment: aggregate `std::stringstream ss' has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: @Imsorryneedhelp `#include <sstream>`. Google stringstream ftw.

Answer (score 1):

> when i use `cout << lisafilm` it provides me with hex value

This is because you are trying to output an `ofstream`. When this happens, [`operator void*`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/) gets called, producing an arbitrary hex sequence which is tied to your stream, but ultimately is very much useless.

Answer (score 0):

lisafilm is a *stream*, not a *string*

If you want to copy lisafilm to cout something like `cout << lisafilm.rdbuf();` would do the trick (assuming that lisafilm is an ostream or istream and that lisafilm's position is the start of the file.

Your code is very poorly formatted, I don't think what you posted would compile. If you clean it up stackoverflow may be able to help you more.